Confusion about the multidimensional Fourier expansion of products
Consider two multidimensional Fourier expansions for real functions U and V:
$$ U(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_\mathbf{k} u_{\mathbf{k}}e^{-i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x}} $$
$$ V(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_\mathbf{k} v_{\mathbf{k}}e^{-i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x}} $$
The expansion of the product will be
$$ U(\mathbf{x}) V(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_\mathbf{k} \big( \sum_\mathbf{k'} u_{\mathbf{k} - \mathbf{k'}} v_{\mathbf{k'}} \big) e^{-i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x}} $$
Now, this sums extends for negative coordinates in the k-space, however for negative indices I understand this should be the c.c. of the coefficient with one sign flipped
So if I have in 2D a coefficient $u_{2,3}$, we should have that $u_{2,3} = \overline{u_{2,-3}} = \overline{\overline{u_{-2,-3}}} = u_{-2,-3}$, correct?
For instance, doing the convolution above, the $(0,0)$ coefficient, assuming both $u$ and $v$ are truncated for $|k_x| \leq 3$, $|k_y| \leq 3$, turns out as:
$$ (uv)_{0,0} = u_{0,0} v_{0,0} + u_{0,1} \overline{v_{0,1}} + u_{0,2} \overline{v_{0,2}} + u_{0,3} \overline{v_{0,3}} + u_{1,0} \overline{v_{1,0}} + u_{1,1} v_{1,1} + u_{1,2} v_{1,2} + u_{1,3} v_{1,3} + u_{2,0} \overline{v_{2,0}} + u_{2,1} v_{2,1} + u_{2,2} v_{2,2} + u_{2,3} v_{2,3} $$
In the 1D case, the simplification is obvious as $c_{-k_x} = \overline{ c_{k_x}}$. However in N dimensions, you have $2^N$ sectors that have one or more negative components of $\mathbf{k'}$.
I used to remember that for the $0,0$ element, only the 1st term was present. The negative coefficients for higher $k$ didn't enter the coefficients of smaller $k$, but I'm not sure how they were being simplified in the multidimensional case.
question:
what is the exact range of indices $\mathbf{k'}$ on the expression $\sum_\mathbf{k'} u_{\mathbf{k} - \mathbf{k'}} v_{\mathbf{k'}}$ when $\mathbf{k}$ is a multidimensionally indexed?
in 2D or N-dimensions, can we simplify the Fourier series with only the coefficients with positive indices, or there needs to be at least $2^{N-1}$ sectors of indices?
For real functions, do we have to conjugate on every sign flip of the index, or is only conjugated for  $- \mathbf{k'}$ as a vector? In this case we cannot simply express the coefficients as the sector of fully positive coefficients?

Why not compute the first few terms explicitly? You'll see the pattern.

@Aruralreader isn't that what I did above? $(uv){0,0}$ is the first term, but since I'm including the negative ones any coefficient $v{\mathbf{k'}}$ satisfying $\mathbf{k} + \mathbf{k'} = 0$ is in there, and it would become infinite as I further refine the truncation

Let's go over the 1D case. In this case we simply have $u_{-k_0} = \overline{u_{k_0}}$ for Fourier coefficients describing a real-valued function, and the minimal non-redundant data we need to describe a Fourier series are the positive k-indices including the zero. All the negative-index coefficients are redundant.
In the 2D case and above, it is false that flipping a sign of the k-indices will be equal to the conjugate with the unflipped sign. What is true is just that
$$ u_{-k_x,-k_y} = \int_\Omega U(x,y) e^{i (k_x x + k_y y) } dx dy = \overline{ u_{k_x, k_y}}  $$
If U(x,y) has no mirror symmetries and the only constraint it is subject to is that it must be real, then the only thing we can say is this. This implies that the minimal non-redundant data required for a multi-dimensional series is actually the Projective k-space, that is, is the k-space where we only need one complex number to describe an amplitude both at a k-space lattice point and its vectorial opposite:
$$ u_{\mathbf{-k'}} = \overline{ u_{\mathbf{k'}} } $$
In the 2D case, this turns out to be two quadrants: one where both k-indices have the same sign, and another where both k-indices have the opposite sign. Sometimes the convention in many textbooks is to just take half the infinite sum in the last axis:
$$ U(x,y) = \sum_{k_x = -\infty} ^{\infty} \sum_{k_y = 0} ^{\infty} u_{k_x,k_y} e^{-i( k_x x + k_y y)} $$
So in higher dimensions, the non-redundant data will always require some negative indices (unless the function has additional symmetries)
In fact, the negative quadrant still has a redundancy when $k_y = 0$, as the negative $k_x$ are redundant. More precisely, the non-redundant 2D data is the non-redundant 1D data on the x-axis, plus either the strictly y-positive half-plane above the x-axis, or the strictly y-negative half place below the x-axis.
In N dimensions, we have $2^N$ sectors. The non-redundant N-dimensional data can be constructed recursively by taking the non-redundant N-1-dimensional data and adding either a strictly positive or strictly negative half-space along the newly added dimension.
Answering the question regarding the convolution sum: all the terms in the expansion must be included as long as they are nonzero. If a $u_{\mathbf{k'}}$ coefficient is not present in the non-redundant data, but $u_{\mathbf{-k'}}$ is present and non-zero, then its conjugate value must be included.
